# (UWP) When you x:Bind an event to a eventhandler in VM, does the bind have to be unset manually when navigating to new View?

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml

As we all know, UWP-based apps can use x:Bind to bind events to their corresponding handlers - wherever they may be located.

Now I have several Views that I navigate to. Each of these Views contain events that x:Bind to a single eventhandler located in the ViewModel. The ViewModel is never unloaded during the lifetime of the app.

When I navigate to a different View, do the x:Bind links get cleared automatically or do I have to implement code to do this myself? Remember that even though the View changes, I am using the same instance of the ViewModel here.

DO note that I am developing a UWP application, and so any suggestions given would have to apply to that platform. I say that because people still tend to give advice that relates to WPF, even when I clearly state that the app is UWP-based.

Thanks! :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the View is unloaded so is the binding.  If the View is still alive so is the binding.  The difference is with XAML if the View isn't Visible you're not really consuming too many resources to le3t the binding continue.  The only thing that may give you a noticeable impact would be animations on items during binding; which still consumes resources (although less) even if the View isn't visible.

The short answer is no as long as the View is unloaded. And as far as using the same ViewModel goes there's nothing wrong with that and in fact I prefer to do that myself when I can.  But just as suggestion, good practice is still to design the ViewModel to work the same whether it's a new one or the same one; if there's data that needs to be constant I suggest the ViewModel push that off to the Model.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. Clear enough for me.